# Trigger problems in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table named `reservation` which consists of column `reservationStatus` and `place` and another table `spot` which consists of `spot_id` and `spot_status`.
i have created a trigger in reservation table which should activate after the reservationStatus has been set to 0. but it is not working

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER spotCancel
AFTER UPDATE ON reservation
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF NEW.reservationStatus = 0 AND OLD.place <=>  'AbcMall' THEN
UPDATE spot SET spot_status = 0 WHERE spot_id <=> OLD.spot_id;
END IF;

IF NEW.reservationStatus = 0 AND OLD.place <=> 'XyzGym' THEN
UPDATE spot1 SET spot_status =0 WHERE spot_id <=> OLD.spot_id;

END IF;
END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

This query fails silently everytime and i couldnot find the error. I am using xampp and mysql innoDB storage engine.

Comment: show us the error, you'r getting

Comment: i am not getting any error! that's the main problem! query is failing and i am not getting any errors

Comment: what is "show triggers;" outputting? do you have any other trigger for the same combination of triggering events? Add this line and re-execute the trigger with what Barmar has suggested DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS spotCancel$$

Comment: if that doesn't work still go ahead and create a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an `END IF`.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER spotCancel
AFTER UPDATE ON reservation
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF NEW.reservationStatus = 0 AND OLD.place <=>  'Abc' THEN
        UPDATE spot SET spot_status = 0 WHERE spot_id <=> OLD.spot_id;
    END IF;

    IF NEW.reservationStatus = 0 AND OLD.place <=> 'Def' THEN
        UPDATE spot1 SET spot_status =0 WHERE spot_id <=> OLD.spot_id;
    END IF;

END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I am new to triggers and events! i corrected my code ! but still trigger is not being created